# How to hide cmd window when run perl in python?

Tags: python, perl

I write the main application with python and build it to windows *.exe file, and now need to call a 3rd party perl script.

I use,

```
cmd = "perl fileconverter.pl"
subprocess.call(cmd)
```

Everything works well except the cmd window, which will pop up when subprocess.call(cmd) is called.
Question is, how to hide the cmd window in this situation?

Comment: It should reuse the console already being used by Python. Does your Python program have a console? If so, can you provide the output of `perl -V:archname`?

Comment: @ikegami, here is archname='MSWin32-x64-multi-thread, also, I replace 'perl' with 'wperl' in command string as you suggested in Answers, console is hidden now, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `wperl` instead of `perl`.

---

If your program is running in a console, `perl` should reuse the same console.

```
>perl -e"system 'perl -Esay+123'"
123
```

(I don't have Python installed, but the same applies no matter what launches `perl`.)

But maybe the Python is running without a console. Then `perl` will create itself a console.

Another answer shows you how to hide this console when using Python, and it's a great solution. But there's a simple Perl-specific option you can also use.

Strawberry Perl (and I think ActivePerl, and probably all builds of Perl for Windows) provide not just `perl.exe`, but `wperl.exe`.<sup>[1]</sup> The latter is identical to the former, except it uses a hidden console.<sup>[2]</sup> So all you would need to do is change `perl` to `wperl`.

---

1. I don't count builds of Perl for unix emulation environments (Cygwin, MSYS, MSYS2) as Windows builds of Perl.
2. The binaries differ by only one bit.

Answer (score 2):

Can't reproduce it, but try setting [startupinfo](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.STARTUPINFO) like this:

```
cmd = "perl fileconverter.pl"

startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
startupinfo.dwFlags = subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE | subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW
startupinfo.wShowWindow = subprocess.SW_HIDE
subprocess.call(cmd, startupinfo=startupinfo)
```